# C++ using lists to solve sudoku

Tags: c++, arrays, list, sudoku, solver

I'm trying to make a sudoku solver in c++. I want to keep an array from [9] by [9] (obviously). I'm now figuring out a way to keep track of the possible values. I thought about a list for every entry in the array. So the list has initially the numbers 1 to 9, and every iteration I would be able to get rid of some values.

Now my question is, can I assign one list to every entry in the 2D array, if so how? And else is there an other/better option?

I'm a starter programmer and this is basicly my first project in c++. 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, but why an array `[9][9]`?  Each individual cell is part of _three_ higher level groupings: line, column and block; unless you can somehow manage all three, there's no real advantage (and some disadvantages) over just using `Cell board[81];`.

Comment: Also: why do you want to keep multiple possible values in each cell?

Comment: In fact, you probably want a few arrays of size `[81]`. The first array contains known correct numbers, and is initialized with the given numbers. Next, you have an array of possibilities, which stores 9 bits per cell. And (here's the dirty trick to Sudoku solving) you want to be able to recurse: when you get stuck, copy those arrays, and guess a number. If you can solve that copy, good. If it didn't work, you can scratch the guessed number from the original list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create an array of sets by doing

```
std::array<std::set<int>,81> possibleValues;
```

for example. You can fill this array with all possibilities by writing

```
const auto allPossible = std::set<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
std::fill( std::begin(possibleValues), std::end(possibleValues), 
    allPossible );
```

if you are using a modern C++11 compiler. This is how you can set/clear and test each entry:

```
possibleValues[x+9*y].insert( n ); // sets that n is possible at (x,y).
possibleValues[x+9*y].erase( n ); // clears the possibility of having n at (x,y).
possibleValues[x+9*y].count( n ) != 0 // tells, if n is possible at (x,y).
```

If performance is an issue, you might want to use bit operations rather than (relatively) heavyweight `std::set` operations. In this case use

```
std::array<short, 81> possibleValues;
std::fill( begin(possibleValues), end(possibleValues), (1<<10)-1 );
```

The value `n` is possible for the field `(x,y)`, if and only if `possibleValues[x+9*y] & (1<<n) != 0`, where all indices start at 0 in this case.

Comment: so std::array is an array of 81 long with each entry possible values from 1 - 9 ? and I want to delete possibilities until only one left?

Comment: No. If a value is possible is encoded in the different bits of each integer. The least significant bit tells, if the value 0 is possible. The next least significant bit tells, if the value 1 is possible. And so forth. If you're not familiar with the binary system, I'd suggest to use the `std::array<std::set<int>,81>` type. That's an array of sets. Each set can contain the numbers 0,1,...,8 or 1,...,9, if you prefer. I've shown how to set new possibilities and how to remove possibilities (clear). If you're not familiar with these container types, that might be a very hard project to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use a set of one bit flags for each square, e.g.

```
uint16_t board[9][9]; // 16 x 1 bit flags for each square where 9 bits are used
                      // to represent possible values for the square
```

Then you can use bitwise operators to set/clear/test each bit, e.g.

```
board[i][j] |= (1 << n);  // set bit n at board position i, j

board[i][j] &= ~(1 << n); // clear bit n at board position i, j

test = (board[i][j] & (1 << n)) != 0; // test bit n at board position i, j
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always think of your sudoku as a 3D array making your 3D dimension to store the possible values and mainly:

```
// set "1" in cell's which index corespond to a possible value for the Sudoku cell
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            arr[x][y][i] = 1;
```

and `arr[x][y][0]` contains the value of your Sudoku.

to remoove for exemple the value of "5" as a possibility for the cell `[x][y]` just change the value of `arr[x][y][5] = 0`